# Expectation of the output of a code with pointers & references mixture

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, cout

If we have this segment of code:

```
char *i="Hello";

cout<<i<<endl;
cout<<*i<<endl;
cout<<&i<<endl;
cout<<*&i<<endl;
cout<<&*i<<endl;
cout<<*i**i<<endl;
```

How can we expect & explain the output before directly complie the code?

Comment: You usually explain things using words.

Comment: An exercise like this is usually intended to demonstrate that you understand dereference `*` and address `&` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly basic that you don't need to compile it to know what's happening.

```
cout<<i<<endl;
```

You're outputting the `char*` (C-string) `i`, so `Hello` (plus newline) is printed.

---

```
cout<<*i<<endl;
```

`*i` is the first `char` of `i`, `'H'`, and that's what's printed.

---

```
cout<<&i<<endl;
```

This will just print the address of `i` (`char**`).

---

```
cout<<*&i<<endl;
```

ie. `*(&i)`. This will get the address of `i` as above, giving you a `char**`, then dereference that address to give you the `char*` that is `i`. So this'll print the same as the first line.

---

```
cout<<&*i<<endl;
```

ie. `&(*i)`. This will dereference `i` to give you the first `char` in the string (`'H'`), and then get the address of that `char` to give you a `char*`. That `char*` is the same the above, `i`.

---

```
cout<<*i**i<<endl;
```

ie. `(*i) * (*i)`. As you know by the second line, `*i` is `'H'`, and the `char` `'H'` has the decimal value 72. When performing multiplication on the `char`s, they'll be promoted to `int`. So the output will be the `int` result of 72 multiplied by 72, which is 5184.

---

Therefore that snippet will output:

```
Hello
H
<The address of i>
Hello
Hello
5184
```